# Randomise between activities

Tags: android, android-activity

If I have 3 activities, how would I set up a randomise between the activities so it picks one out of the three and displays that?

So far I have tried the following code:

```
package com.ICTrevisionapp;

import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class randomquiz extends Activity { 
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.quiz);  
        Button generate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.generate); 
        generate.setOnClickListener(generateListener); 
    } 
    private OnClickListener generateListener = new OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View v){ 
            Random generator = new Random(); 
            int number = generator.nextInt(2); 
            Intent intent = null; 
            switch(number){ 
            case 0: 
            intent = new Intent(randomquiz.this, topicstotopicone.class); 
            break; 
            case 1: 
            intent = new Intent(randomquiz.this, topicstotopictwo.class); 
            break; 
            case 2: 
            intent = new Intent(randomquiz.this, topicstotopicthree.class); 
            break; 
            } 
            startActivity(intent); 
        }
};
}
```

Is this also correct for the manifest :

> ```
>   <activity
>         android:name=".randomquiz"
>         android:label="@string/app_name" >
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.topicstotopicone" />
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.topicstotopictwo" />
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.topicstotopicthree" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity
> ```

However this runs the application but when the button is pressed, nothing is acomplished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code does not make much sense . it would be enough to do this:

```
public void onClick(View v){
    Random generator = new Random();
    int number = generator.nextInt(3);
    Intent intent = null;
    switch(number){
    case 0:
    intent = new Intent(randomquiz.this, topicstotopicone.class);
    break;
    case 1:
    intent = new Intent(randomquiz.this, topicstotopictwo.class);
    break;
    case 2:
    intent = new Intent(randomquiz.this, topicstotopicthree.class);
    break;
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Your Activities will also have to be declared in your Android Manifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name=".randomquiz"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".topicstotopicone"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".topicstotopictwo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".topicstotopicthree"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
</activity>
```

Comment: I tried this, yet nothing still happens. The button doesnt link to any of the other pages. I replaced my public void with this, do i need to add anything to the manifest? Thanks

Comment: @azzahayre: You need to add your activities in your manifest, if you haven't added them already. I think you can also try replacing `Intent intent = null;`  with `Intent intent = this;`.

Comment: Would i have to add 3 different actions into the manifest, as its random to three different pages? Once i press the button, nothing happens. Ive edited the code above to the new code. Thanks for the help so far

Comment: Every activity in you application needs to be declared in the manifest. Not quite as you have done, but I updated my answer with an example of this too.